# Swift Comparing two color objects to see if their color is the same with touch

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

The choiceBall is set to black but randomly changes color to match one of the other balls with each tap. The idea is that I tap the the other balls according to what the choiceBall's color is.

For Example: The choiceBall turns blue. I touch the blue ball. The choiceBall turns red I touch the red ball etc.

How can I check if I have tapped the right ball according to the choiceBall. So that I can implement a score board to keep score.

Thanks for any help :)

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

   var choiceBall = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 50)
   var blueBall = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 50)
   var greenBall = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 50)
   var yellowBall = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 50)
   var redBall = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 50)

   var array = [SKColor(red: 0.62, green: 0.07, blue: 0.04, alpha: 1), SKColor(red: 0, green: 0.6, blue: 0.8, alpha: 1), SKColor(red: 0, green: 0.69, blue: 0.1, alpha: 1), SKColor(red: 0.93, green: 0.93, blue: 0, alpha: 1)]

 override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    choiceBall.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width / 2, self.frame.size.height / 2)
    choiceBall.fillColor = SKColor.blackColor()
    self.addChild(choiceBall)

    blueBall.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width * 0.35, self.frame.size.height * 0.25)
    blueBall.fillColor = SKColor(red: 0, green: 0.6, blue: 0.8, alpha: 1)
    self.addChild(blueBall)

    redBall.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width * 0.65, self.frame.size.height * 0.75)
    redBall.fillColor = SKColor(red: 0.62, green: 0.07, blue: 0.04, alpha: 1)
    self.addChild(redBall)

    yellowBall.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width * 0.35, self.frame.size.height * 0.75)
    yellowBall.fillColor = SKColor(red: 0.93, green: 0.93, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
    self.addChild(yellowBall)

    greenBall.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width * 0.65, self.frame.size.height * 0.25)
    greenBall.fillColor = SKColor(red: 0, green: 0.69, blue: 0.1, alpha: 1)
    self.addChild(greenBall)
}

 override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

    let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(array.count)))
    choiceBall.fillColor = array[randomIndex]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you need to check all touches with collisions with all balls and if they collide, you can check colors. Don't forget to skip choice ball if you don't want it to be checked for taps as well.

```
for t in touches { // check each touch
    let touch = t as! UITouch // convert to UITouch for pre Swift 2.0
    let pos = touch.locationInNode(self) // find touch position

    for child in self.children { // check each children in scene
        if let ball = child as? SKShapeNode { // convert child to the shape node
            if ball !== choiceBall && ball.containsPoint(pos) { // check for collision, but skip if it's a choice ball
                if ball.fillColor == choiceBall.fillColor { // collision found, check color
                    // do your stuff, colors match
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this partly pseudo code? I am new to coding and relatively understand the code itself, but not the for in loop. I get and error: 
let pos = t.locationInNode(self)
NSObject does not have a member locationInNode

Comment: What Xcode version are you using? In Xcode 7 and Swift 2.0 `touchesBegan` method knows that `touches` Set consists of `UITouch` objects. However in older versions you might need to convert `t` to UITouch. Add a line: `let touch = t as! UITouch` right before the line that gets error. Of course replace next line to use `touch` instead of `t`.

Comment: I have implemented the code and now it works, kind of. There seems to be a problem with the detection. Where the comment //do your stuff, colors match I put in 
println("Point")
But it does not print "Point" to the console each time I hit the correct ball. I have a theory why. In my node count it says 11 nodes. One for my label and then 2 nodes for each ball. But there are only 5 balls. Do you know why the balls seem to multiply by 2 and do you think that has something to do with it not being able to detect collision.

Comment: You can try checking touch coordinates and each node coordinates to see if they are near. If not try to find out why they differ. As well check if your  `didMoveToView ` gets called once to see why there are 2 nodes for each ball but even in then your `println` should just be called twice then. Try to debug code checking `if ball !== choiceBall && ball.containsPoint(pos)` why it fails when it's not supposed to.

Comment: I have changed the code so that the balls contain textures. The node count is now as it should be but the code still doesn't seem to work 100% here is the link -->
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31614021/collision-checking-issues)