# Collision checking issues

Tags: swift, if-statement, sprite-kit

The code checks if the user taps a ball with the same texture as a ball that randomly changes textures. But in my console "Point" is only printed occasionally although I tap on the ball with the same texture as the ball that randomly changes texture. How can this be fixed. Has this something to do with adding a physicsBody to the other balls?

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

    var array = [blueTexture, redTexture, greenTexture, yellowTexture]// var with value of textures

    var blackB = childNodeWithName("changeBall") as! SKSpriteNode

    let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(array.count)))
    blackB.texture = array[randomIndex] // blackB is given a random texture 

    for t in touches { // check each touch

        let touch = t as! UITouch
        let pos = touch.locationInNode(self) // find touch position

        for child in self.children { // check each children in scene
            if let ball = child as? SKSpriteNode{ 
                if ball !== blackB && ball.containsPoint(pos) { // check for collision, but skip if it's a blackB
                    if ball.texture == blackB.texture { // collision found, check color
                        println("POINT")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: You can try to replace `for child in self.children {` with `if let child = self.nodeAtPoint(pos) {`, then you can remove `&& ball.containsPoint(pos)`, maybe that helps

Comment: When I replace the code I get an error. `if let child = self.nodeAtPoint(pos) {` //error: Bound value in a conditional biding must be of Option type
Does this have something to do with the fact that I'm on Xcode6 and using Swift 1.2

Comment: just remove `if` and square brackets, it just says there's nothing to check, it will always be true

Comment: @KleMiX there is an answer here below. It works but again not every time. Do you have a theory why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some observations...

1. `nodeAtPoint(pos)` can replace the `for` loop over child nodes
2. `ball.containsPoint(pos)` is not needed because `nodeAtPoint` performs the same test
3. `ball !== blackB` should be `ball != blackB`
4. Perhaps changing to a random texture after checking for a texture match makes more sense

An implementation with the above changes

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

    var array = [blueTexture, redTexture, greenTexture, yellowTexture]
    var blackB = childNodeWithName("changeBall") as! SKSpriteNode

    if let touch = touches.first as? UITouch {
        let pos = touch.locationInNode(self)
        if let ball = nodeAtPoint(pos) as? SKSpriteNode {
            if ball != blackB && ball.texture == blackB.texture {
                println("POINT")
            }
        }
    }
    // Change texture after checking for a texture match
    let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(array.count)))
    blackB.texture = array[randomIndex]
}
```

Comment: I have figured out the problem partly. The code works in this way. If the blackB texture has changed from red and is now yellow. I won't get a point for taping the yellow ball unless I tap it when the blackB texture was red. So what it is basically saying: The blackB is going to change color randomly and you will only get a point if you can guess what the next color will be. Can anybody help me how to edit the code so this doesn't happen. If further explaining is needed please ask me.

Comment: If I wanted to set an if statement for the 
`let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(array.count)))`
`blackB.texture = array[randomIndex]`
So that the blackB would only change color when the user has tapped on the correct ball. For instance. If the blackB.texture has changed into yellow and I tap the red ball. blackB.texture will still change color. This is problematic because then users can spam a single ball and will get a point when blackB is changed into set color.
Note: There is a timer for only one minute so that is why I am asking.

Comment: If you move the `let rand...` and `blackB.texture = ...` statements in the `if` block with the `println`, the ball will change color only when the user tapped on the correct color.

Comment: I tried that earlier but the problem is that blackB is set to a black texture that none of the other balls have so the code `if ball != blackB && ball.texture == blackB.texture {` will never execute since `ball.texture == blackB.texture` will never be true.
I solved the solution by removing the black texture and setting it by default to blue so that the code will run.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you wish that something must happen when you touch the same textured ball...

```js
if ball.texture == blackB.texture { 
  println("POINT"); //This is the only instruction read by the computer and nothing else
}

if ball.texture == blackB.texture {
  println("POINT");
  doSomething();//Insert expected function like here
}
```

*UPDATE*

```js
if(ball.texture == blackB.texture){
  println("POINT");
  score+=1;
  label.text = String(score); // Update the label.text value everytime score changes
}
```

Comment: Precisely. I added `score += 1` under the if statement and now I have a label. `label.text = "Score:" + String(score)` Of course there is more code for the label. For instance it's position and font size and all that. But the label doesn't keep score. It's always default. Score:0

Comment: Now the label does indeed hold score but it still doesn't follow 100% When I tap the right colored ball it sometimes gives me a point and sometimes not. I have no idea why this is.